# How to get embedded closed capions (subtitles) from a videofile using Azure Media Services v3?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services

We're using [Azure Media Services v3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/) to store and stream videos (uploaded by our clients) to our clients and it works fine.
Sometimes our clients upload these files with embedded subtitles/closed captions and we would like to display them. Is there any way to get those CC files out of the video?

We've already tried to [analyze the videos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/analyze-videos-tutorial-with-api), but all we've got were auto-generated subtitles. We couldn't figure out how to get the embedded CCs via AMSv3.

We've used the following video file:

https://github.com/Matroska-Org/matroska-test-files/blob/master/test_files/test5.mkv

We've got the following WEBVTT file:

https://pastebin.com/6MQazv1m

```
00:00:04.980 --> 00:00:09.028

overrode us no and it is here just
```

What we need is embedded into the "test5.mkv".

Comment: Can you provide us with a compete, minimal, verifiable example? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve When I try to open your github link I get this message, "(Sorry about that, but we can’t show files that are this big right now.)" and I don't want to have to download the entire raw file.

Comment: To clarify, your clients are uploading files like the test5,mkv file, where there are subtitle or closed caption tracks interleaved with video and audio. And you want these to be extracted during the encoding process - are you using the extracted files for delivery to viewers, or as metadata to help search for videos?

Comment: Yes, they are uploading files like test5.mkv with subtitle/cc. We use these uploaded and encoded video files to stream them to our customers.
We want to display these subtitles in Azure Media Player.

Answer (score 0):

So the scenario is to use one file as the video/audio source, and another separate (aka side-car) file with captions/subtitles, encode these, and ensure that captions/subtitles playback via Azure Media Player.

Recommended option: Azure Media Player [supports](https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/samples/dynamic_webvtt.html) playing back separate WebVTT files, so you would encode the video/audio source, and use an open source tool like [Subtitle Edit](https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit) to generate VTT files.

Else, if you require the service to produce VTT files, then you would need to use the Premium Encoder. Please contact us via amshelp@microsoft.com if you want to pursue this route.